# Custom templates reset password problems in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, authentication, iron-router, reset-password

I´m still working on my own user login/register system (working with accounts-password package). I´m too near to the glory;), but my system is crashing with reset password form...

I have invested many hours to solve the problem, but at the moment, I don´t have any solution...
I´m using iron:route package for routing and accounts-password to manage users.

The problem is the next one:

When I receive the email with the link to the reset-password route, the page is blank...The form/template is not rendered... I think that could be a problem configuring the reset-passowrd Route/Template but I´m not sure...
Any suggestion please?? I´m beginning with Meteor, and this Login system is my first challenge... I´m very close to finish the system but this problem is getting crazy me... this is a picture of my site (following the reset link from the email received)...it looks like the URL is taking right the reset password token, but is not working...The console doesn´t get any error...Many thanks in advance. All suggestions are welcome[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzfC0.png)

This is my code

**CLIENT js**

```
//config reset password
if (Accounts._resetPasswordToken) {
  Session.set('resetPasswordToken', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
}
//Router reset password

  Router.route('/reset-password/:token', function () {
    this.layout('ResetLayout');

    this.render('ResetPassword', {
    to:"ResetPassword"
    });
});

Template.ResetPassword.helpers({
 resetPassword: function(){
    return Session.get('resetPasswordToken');
    console.log('resetPasswordToken');
  }
});
```

**SERVER js**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function(token) {
    return Meteor.absoluteUrl('reset-password/' + token);
  };

});
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="ResetLayout">
    <div class="container">     
      {{> yield "ResetPassword"}}
    </div> 
</template>


<template name="ResetPassword">
    {{#if resetPassword}}
        <div  id="resetPassword">
            <form  class="resetPasswordForm" method="post">
                <input id="resetPasswordPassword" name="password" placeholder="New Password" type="password" >
                <input id="resetPasswordPasswordConfirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm" type="password" >
                <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Reset">
            </form>
            <!-- end #reset-password-form -->
        </div>    
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: If you write some `Hello World` in the template outside the `{{#if resetPassword}}`, does that get shown?

Comment: Is the `resetPassword` function being run? You will need to put the `console.log('resetPasswordToken');` line _before_ you `return` from the function if you want to see it.

Comment: @PaulS, yes! if  I write hello world outside {{#if resetPassword}} I can see the message right! (good tip for debuging by the way!). I guess so, that the problem is in my template.ResetPassword.helpers?...Then, I assume that routing is working fine...mmm... I don´t understand what is the problem...:(

Comment: So `Session.get('resetPasswordToken')` isn't truthy, so either the following line hasn't yet fired: `Session.set('resetPasswordToken', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);` **or** `Accounts._resetPasswordToken` isn't what you expect

Comment: Thanks @biofractal! I have put the line before return, your are right ! (right now this line is commented)

Comment: Thanks for you fast reply @PaulS.! yes, I understand the logic, but I don´t understand what could be the reason for these lines are not fired right...(Sesion.set or Accounts.__resetPasswordToken) ...apparently, the token is working fine... I think that I´m a bit lost about Tokens and Accounts... Could you explain a bit in depth about your suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user3362713 do another debug step to narrow it down; put a log in both of these methods so you can see 1. if they invoke, 2. the order in which they invoke, 3. the actual values they have

Comment: My guess is that the `Session.set` line did not fire since the user is not necessarily logged in when navigating to the link (this depends on how you set up the login tokens to expire). You should probably add `Session.set('resetPasswordToken', this.params.token)` inside the route.

Comment: @DavidKleiman, if I understand correctly, I must change this line in client.js ? `if(Accounts._resetPasswordToken) {
  Session.set('resetPasswordToken', this.params.token);
} `I have made the change but is not working...:(. When you say "inside the route", could you show me some example? Im a bit confuse... Many thanks in advance!

Comment: OK!! solved @DavidKleiman!! finally I understand your suggestion, and magic, it works!! I add this line in my reset password route : `Router.route('/reset-password/:token', function () {
    Session.set('resetPasswordToken', this.params.token);
    this.layout('ResetLayout');

    this.render('ResetPassword', {
    to:"ResetPassword"
    });
});` you are my hero!!;)

Comment: many thanks for your suggestion @PaulS.. Finally, was not necessary ;)

Comment: @urco sorry if I was unclear.I'm happy you got it working!